# WiFi Drivers for Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I'm new to Linux operating system and I have Kali Linux installed along Windows on my Laptop. I don't know how to connect to WiFi in Kali Linux. When I press the network settings I get Wired Connection, Proxy settings and all but no WiFi. What should I do? I read some answers here and over Google but I can't understand a bit. So please can anyone help step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your wireless adapter requires firmware. Firmware is not always free software, and if it is not then it cannot be distributed together with main software.

Since Kali is a Debian-derived system, inspect your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. As an example, you may see a line (the path may differ in your case):

`deb http://pubmirrors.dal.corespace.com/debian/ testing main`

Edit the line to read:

`deb http://pubmirrors.dal.corespace.com/debian/ testing main contrib non-free`

(i.e. add `contrib non-free`).

Save, run your package manager (does Kali have `synaptic`?) and tell it to reload the repositories. Then within the package manager search for the model of your wireless adapter. Chances are a package from the `non-free` group will contain the firmware you need, so install it and reboot.