# Last Resort: No wifi on Kali

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, broadcom

I guess this is a common issue, but I've had no success with any other answers. I'm trying to install kali uname= 5.7.0-kali1-686-pae on a Dell Latitude D610. lspci tells me that I have
Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4218 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02). iwconfig tells me lo and eth0 no wireless extensions.
What really frustrates me is when I boot a live usb version of kali, the wifi driver works fine, little led comes on, networks show and everything, but after *installing* from the same stick, it does not work when booted from the harddrive.

from https://thetechrim.com/fix-wireless-drivers-problem-in-kali-linux2020/
and [WiFi Drivers for Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241425/wifi-drivers-for-kali-linux)
I have added nonfree drivers and done `apt update` `apt upgrade`, `apt install firmware-linux`,
and I've tried to manually install the driver itself

from https://www.linux.org/threads/dont-have-wifi-on-kali-linux-2020-1.27658/
I've tried
`sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi ; sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

from https://www.kalilinux.in/2020/03/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-in-kali-linux.html
I have tried this broadcom installer

from https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29587-Broadcom-BCM43142-Drivers-on-Kali-Linux
I have done this
`# apt-get update`
`# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms`
`# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma`
`# modprobe wl`

from https://wiki.debian.org/wl
I tried
`# apt-get install -f`
`# dpkg-reconfigure broadcom-sta-dkms`

from [Kali Linux No WiFi Avalibility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396606/kali-linux-no-wifi-avalibility)
I've tried
`sudo apt install network-manager`
`systemctl start NetworkManager.service`

and I've tried a complete reinstall

Please tell me if you need any more info on the device or a commands output. Thank you